# continuity w/ piecewise functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The question: We have two continuous functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Define function $h(x)$ such that for all x<0, we take $f(x)$, and for all x≥0, we take $g(x)$. It is given that $f(0)=g(0)$. Prove h(x) is a continuous function.

What I've tried: I wrote out all the limits we are given from the information, and tried to equate them. I'm really lost as to where to go from here.

Comment: Is this a real analysis course? Are you expected to do an epsilon-delta proof? You could also look at this in terms of left and right limits.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I don't think we're supposed to use left and right limits.

Comment: The proof is fairly straightforward using sequences - reduce to cases where finitely many elements of a sequence converging to zero are negative (or nonnegative), and the case where there exist infinitely many negative and nonnegative elements.

Answer (score 1):

What is the matter with writing out the limits at $x=0$ (continuity for all other points is given)?

Left limit at $0$ is $L=\displaystyle\lim_{\delta\to0}h(-\delta)= f(-\delta)$ and right limit is $R=\displaystyle\lim_{\delta\to0}h(\delta)= g(\delta)$

Since it is given that $f$ and $g$ are continuous, in this small neighborhood $(-\delta,\delta)$ they are equal to $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ respectively

So $L=f(0)=g(0)=R$ and $L=R=g(0)=h(0)$.

So they are continuous

Of course this could (must?) be fleshed out and written in a more rigorous manner. That is up to you now.

Comment: So it's enough to just state that it is continuous at every point by the givens?

Comment: @sutavala At every negative value of $x$, $h$ is equal to $f$, and thus continuous. Likewise at every positive value of $x$. It is only at $x = 0$ that there is anything substantial to show.

Answer (score 1):

Function $\ h\ $ is continuous on two CLOSED sets of the whole space $\ \Bbb R,\ $ namely on the closed half-lines, and the union of these two sets is the entire space (the two cover our space $\ \Bbb R).$

In general,

> **THEOREM**  Consider a function $\ h:X\to Y\ $ between two topological spaces $\ X\ Y.\ $ Let $\ \mathcal F\ $ be a finite family of closed subsets of topological space $\ X\ $ such that $\ \bigcup \mathcal F\ = X.\ $
>   Assume also that restriction $\ H|F:F\to Y\ $ is continuous for every $\ F\in\mathcal F.\ $ Then function $\ h\ $ is continuous.

The proof is instant: for every closed set $\ C\ $ of $\ Y,\ $ prove that $\ h^{-1}(C)\ $ is closed in $\ X.$

**REMARK** Replace word *closed* by *open* each time in the above theorem (and in the hint under it), and you'll get again a theorem (and a hint of a proof) -- furthermore(!), remove word *finite*, and the theorem about open sets will still hold and will be more general (hence better!).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Suppose $h$ is not continuous at $x_0$.  What can you deduce for each of $x_0 < 0$, $x_0 = 0$, and $x_0 > 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Continuity at points other then  $0$ is obvious. For continuity at $0$ let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $\delta_1 >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|x| <\delta_1$. Choose $\delta_2 >0$ such that $|g(x)-g(0)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|x| <\delta_2$. Let $\delta =\min \{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. Then $|h(x)-h(0)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|x| <\delta$: just consider the cases $x<0$ and $x \geq 0$ to see why this is true.